# while (getchar () != '\n' );

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, getchar

I have the following for loop, I am prompting the user to enter a 4 digit pin and hit enter. Can someone explain to me what the while loop is really doing because I don't fully understand it.

```
//user input for pin
for(i = 0; i < PIN_LENGTH; i++)
{
    printf("Enter digit %d of your PIN: ", i);
    user_pin[i] = getchar();
    while (getchar() != '\n'); //what is this line doing??
}
```

Comment: It's terribly broken -- what happens if `getchar()` gets `EOF`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Im new to C, I have no idea. What does it do?

Comment: crash because of undefined behavior is my first guess

Comment: It loops forever, since `EOF != '\n'`, and never will be.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by others, this loop discards unwanted characters from `stdin` so that the next input function has a clean stream, and in particular it discards the `\n` that follows the last character entered by the user. But, `getchar()` returns `EOF` in the event of a read error, so the loop should test for `EOF` also, like this:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
    continue;  // discard unwanted characters
```

Also note that, if `stdin` has been redirected, it is possible to reach `EOF` without encountering a `\n`. And, as @chqrlie pointed out in the comments, the user can signal an `EOF` from the terminal by entering `Ctrl-D` in Linux, or `Ctrl-Z` in Windows. Hence the importance of testing for `EOF` explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

When you give input to the program, then you end it with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. This key is sent to your program as a newline.

What the loop does is to read and discard characters until it has read the newline. It flushes the input buffer.

If you don't do this, then the next main `getchar` call would return the newline instead of the digit you expect.

Comment: But there is a problem: The loop will only terminate if it encounters a newline `\n` character. For anything else it will spin ad-infinitum. This is clearly not the right way to flush an input buffer.

Comment: The C Reference books says something like while( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); but in my case omitting the EOF works fine. Possibly a fluke on my part.

Comment: @Konahrik16 Yes you really need to check for `EOF` as well. And remember that `getchar` return an `int`.

Comment: @Konahrik16: it seems to work because you did not give your program the input that would make it fail: try typing `1` and `control-D` in linux or `1`, `control-Z` and `enter` in Windows.

Answer (score 3):

The next line is discarding the possible extra chars that the user may have inputted, and also the linefeed char that the user *had* to input.

So other `scanf/getchar` methods further in the code are not polluted by this spurious input.

Answer (score -1):

The while loop is used to check when the user will press enter.Enter is considered as '\n'.

Answer (score -1):

That line is a while, so at run-time it will repeat it until  getchar() == '\n'. '\n' is a character  that in ASCII means "enter" key. In this way you can test that the user will not press "enter" without had inserted a number.

Answer (score -1):

The function of this while loop is to clear the users' illegal input. When the input is `'\n'` ,the loop ends.