# My main while loop will run, and run again when the user enters 'y' or 'n'. Regardless of what the user says

Tags: c

When I added the main while loop, the program just always runs, and runs through again and with a message telling me there is invalid data (from my first input validation). Can anyone show me how to give the user the option to end the program? Basically, I just want to give the user the option to end the program by pressing 'y or 'n'. Would be open to hearing new ideas, such as using a for, or do while loop! I just want the program to go through. I want the user to be able to go through as many times as they want, while having the option to leave after each run through.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Declare functions
void displayWelcome(void);
double getAverage(double yards, double carries);
void endMessage(void);


int main()
{
//Declare variables
    double yards, carries, average, bestAverage;
    char again = 'y';
//Call function to display welcome message
    displayWelcome();

    while (again == 'y' || again =='Y') {
//Prompt user for the number of yards,
    printf("Enter the number of yards:");
/*
Scan in the value of 'yards' and send user into a loop if they enter 
incorrect data
While loop to validate the data of the value 'yards'
*Works with a numerical value greater than 0
*/
    while ( 1 != scanf( "%lf", &yards ) || yards <= 0)
{

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter a numerical value greater than zero:");
}
//Prompt user for the number of carries, followed by an input scan to get 
//value of carries
    printf("Enter the number of carries:");
/*
Scan in the value of 'yards' and send user into a loop if they enter 
incorrect data
    While loop to validate the data of the value 'carries'
*Works with a numerical value greater than zero
*/
    while ( 1 != scanf("%lf", & carries) || carries <= 0)
{
//Refreshes the input value of the variable 'carries' and prompts the 
//user to type in new value for 'carries'
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter a numerical value greater than zero:");
}

    average = getAverage( yards, carries);
    printf("yards:%g carries:%g average:%g\n", yards, carries, average);
//Give the user the option to run the program again
   printf("Would you like to run the program again? Enter (y)es or (n)o\n");
   scanf("%c\n", &again);
}
   endMessage();
   return 0;
}

    void displayWelcome(void)
{
    printf("Welcome to Football Stats\n");
}

    double getAverage(double yards, double carries)
{
    double average;
    average = yards + carries / 2;
    return average;
}
    void endMessage(void){
    printf("\nThese results were brought to you by ");
}
```

**UPDATE (QUESTION STILL UNANSWERED)** It worked when I presses 'n' to stop the program. However, when I press 'y' to run it again (with the newly input code) it ALSO stops the program. So back to my question, can anyone see WHAT I am doing wrong so that I can give the user the option to close the program?

**FINAL UPDATE** I found the issue. I did "scanf("%c\n", &again);" (clearing the values) when I should have put "scanf("\n%c", &again);". Thank you to everyone who spent the time to help me!

Comment: Your `while` condition is wrong.  Change `(again == 'y' || 'Y')` to `(again == 'y' || again == 'Y')`.

Comment: `scanf("%c\n", &again);`-- it is almost always wrong to use trailing whitespace characters in `scanf()` format strings; this tends to cause problems with interactive input. Most `scanf()` conversion specifiers automatically skip over leading whitespace characters, but `%c`, `%[]` and `%n` are exceptions. You can simply add a leading space to tell `scanf()` to skip leading whitespace characters (of which `\n` is one): `scanf(" %c", &again);`. Also, `fflush(stdin)` causes undefined behavior, according to the Standard; there are better ways to clear the input stream.

Comment: Thank you for educating me on that Mr. Bowling , I love learning new things! Would you give me a few examples of how you would clear the input stream? I am still new-ish to C and would love any extra info you have to spare :)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40958298/is-this-the-proper-way-to-flush-the-c-input-stream), are a [few links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554617/while-getchar-n/40555134#40555134) pertaining to [clearing the input stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715002/how-to-clear-stdin-before-getting-new-input). And here is a link [about trailing whitespace in format strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032984/using-scanfd-with-a-space-after-the-d/43033218#43033218).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
```

Instead of:

```
while (again == 'y' || 'Y')
```

Otherwise, your program thinks you only want to evaluate `'Y'`, which is always true (i.e. non-zero).

Comment: I still am unable to give the user the option to re-run the while loop. Instead, pressing y or n terminates the program. Are you able to see why this is?

Answer (score 1):

```
while (again == 'y' || 'Y') { ...
```

`||` doesn't work like that. `&&` and `||` are used to connect complete boolean expressions. What you mean is:

```
while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y') { ...
```

In C, the expression `'Y'` is just the integer 89, which C interprets as "true" because it is not zero. Thus, your first expression was

```
while (<something> || <true>) { ...
```

which is always true.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the why behind this! Helped me learn something new, I appreciate it :)

Comment: The original question was still unanswered, could you take a look and see if you know why?

Answer (score 1):

The conditions of your while loop evaluate to true.  Like others have mentioned, `(again == 'y' || 'Y')` should be `((again == 'y') || (again == 'Y'))`.  What I have not seen otherwise mentioned is that you also initialize `again` to `'n'`, which would then evaluate to false on the first run.  Instead of initializing again, you could instead transform it do a do-while loop so you always go into the loop on the first time and then evaluate the condition.

```
do {
    ...
} while((again == 'y') || (again == 'Y'));
```