# counter getting reset in while loop in C

Tags: c, loops, counter, reset

I am a newbie in programming and taking integer inputs in unsigned character array, using while loop. Somehow the counter is getting auto reset thus making while loop go infinitely.

```
int i;
unsigned char ab[7];
printf("Enter numbers : ");
i=0;
while(i<7)
{
    scanf(" %d",&ab[i]);
    fflush(stdin);
    i++;
    printf("\nvalue of i : %d",i);
}
```

By printing counter value , I got to know that counter is getting reset.

Can you suggest what is going wrong and why? And what I can do to make it right?

I am compiling it using gcc version details below.

Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix

Thanks

Comment: You tell scanf to write an int into the space reserved for an unsigned char, and it overflows

Comment: Aside: the action of `fflush()` is undefined for an input stream. Another: output the newline at the end of a line, not the beginning.

Comment: Beginners often try to clear the input stream using `fflush`, but this usage is undefined in the C Standard. Some implementations do define this behavior, but you shouldn't rely on it. Instead you should [use something like this typical idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40555134/6879826). Also note that the leading space in `" %d"` is intended to discard leading whitespace (such as newline characters left by a previous operation). But most `scanf` directives (including `%d` and `%hhu`) automatically discard leading whitespace, so this isn't needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `scanf()` %d is for int*, but %hhu assumes unsigned char*.

I also cleaned up the `printf()`, and changed the fflush(stdin) to stdout as it makes no sense for stdin.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
        int i;
        unsigned char ab[7];
        printf("Enter numbers : ");
        i=0;
        while(i<7)
        {
                scanf("%hhu", &ab[i]);
                i++;
                printf("value of i : %d\n",i);
                fflush(stdout);
        }

}
```

This works:

```
% counter
Enter numbers : 1
value of i : 1
2
value of i : 2
3
value of i : 3
4
value of i : 4
5
value of i : 5
6
value of i : 6
7
value of i : 7
%
```